# Collision method only using one item from list

Tags: c#, collision-detection, monogame

I've made a temporarily method for collision with all the blocks on the screen. (I used almost the same method in the past, but only for one block at the time.)

So I start in the `Sprite` class. I use a list named `tileCollision` and I make a new list in the constructor for the tiles:

```
public List<Rectangle> tileCollision { get; set; }

public Sprite(GraphicsDevice gd,Texture2D collisionImage, Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position, Point frameSize, Point currentFrame)
{
    this.collisionImage = collisionImage;
    this.textureImage = textureImage;
    this.position = position;
    this.frameSize = frameSize;
    this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
    depth = 0;
    // the Rectangle list
    tileCollision = new List<Rectangle>();
}
```

This is the collision method for the `Sprite` class (NOTE: this class is abstract):

```
public virtual void Collision (Rectangle collisionRect, List<Rectangle> tileCollision)
{
}
```

So now we can have a look at the `PlayerMovement` class, derived from the `Sprite` class. This is the `Collision` method (NOTE: the `TileSprite` class (class for my tiles) also contains a collision rectangle):

```
public override void Collision(Rectangle collisionRect, List<Rectangle> tileCollision)
{
    foreach (Rectangle rect in tileCollision)
    {
        if (collisionRect.Intersects(rect))
        {

            stopping = true;
            walking = false;

            if (collisionRect.X < rect.X)
            {

                fallingTest = false;
                stopping = true;

                if (left)
                {
                    stopping = false;
                    fallingTest = false;
                }
            }

            if (collisionRect.X > rect.X)
            {

                fallingTest = false;
                stopping = true;

                if (!left)
                {
                    stopping = false;
                    fallingTest = false;
                }
            }

            if (collisionRect.Y <= rect.Y - 50)
            {
                ground = true;
                fallingTest = true;
                stopping = false;

                if (moving)
                {
                    walking = true;
                }
            }

            if (collisionRect.Y >= rect.Y + rect.Height)
            {

                stopping = true;

                if (moving)
                {
                    walking = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!collisionRect.Intersects(rect))
        {
            fallingTest = false;
            stopping = false;

            ground = false;

            if (moving)
            {
                walking = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, this is my `SpriteManagerGeneral` class (the class where I "connect" everything for sprite handling). The dirt tiles are added to the `tileCollision` list (NOTE: just for testing):

```
// childTiles list is not used for collision
tileBase.childTiles.Add(dirt);
tileBase.tileCollision.Add(dirt4.bCollisionRect);
tileBase.childTiles.Add(dirt2);
tileBase.tileCollision.Add(dirt3.bCollisionRect);
tileBase.childTiles.Add(dirt3);
tileBase.tileCollision.Add(dirt2.bCollisionRect);
tileBase.childTiles.Add(dirt4);
tileBase.tileCollision.Add(dirt.bCollisionRect);
```

My update method for the collision looks like this:

```
playerBase.children.ForEach(c => c.Collision(player.collisionRect, tileBase.tileCollision));
```

(playerBase is the base of the player that contains a list (`children`) with all the body parts in it)

So now my problem: my problem is that my game only uses the collision logic on the LAST item (Rectangle) added to the `tileCollision`.

You see here that `dirt` is added as the last item, so the collision will work on this block, but not on the others.

I want it so that the method loops through every item instead of the last item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `if (!collisionRect.Intersects(rect))` in my collision method but that means that IF one tile doesn't collide with the player, then it will call this if statement.

So I changed this to `if (!(tileCollision.Any(c => collisionRect.Intersects(c))))` and it works now.

This code translated to English:

If none of the collisionboxes from the tile collide with the player, then call this statement.